# How to export ffurl_register_protocol()?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I have some legacy code that requires `ffurl_register_protocol()` exported. I found this patch:

```
diff --git a/libavformat/Makefile b/libavformat/Makefile
index 0d6cb91..802edd7 100644
--- a/libavformat/Makefile
+++ b/libavformat/Makefile
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 NAME = avformat
 FFLIBS = avcodec avutil
-HEADERS = avformat.h avio.h version.h
+HEADERS = avformat.h avio.h url.h version.h
 OBJS = allformats.o         \
        cutils.o             \
diff --git a/libavformat/libavformat.v b/libavformat/libavformat.v
index 6f11d60..e605135 100644
--- a/libavformat/libavformat.v
+++ b/libavformat/libavformat.v
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 LIBAVFORMAT_$MAJOR {
                 global: av*;
+                ffurl_register_protocol;
           local: *;
 };
```

But, it doesn't help. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
I added `int av_ffurl_register_protocol(URLProtocol *protocol, int size);` to libavformat/avformat.h.

And I added the implementation:

```
int av_ffurl_register_protocol(URLProtocol *protocol, int size)
{
    return ffurl_register_protocol( protocol, size );
}
```

to libavformat/allformats.c

I still have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify libavformat/libavformat.v and add the APIs you want to export and recompile the ffmpeg source code.